# Hide /toggle if clicked outside

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this template over here ( http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar.html ) for my startup in bootstrap learning. I am finding it pretty good to learn. However I have a doubt.

When I open the template in mobile mode, it shows an icon ( Menu icon), when I click it, it shows the sidebar. Now when I click outside the div, ideally it should hide the sidebar (get toggled automatically) but it doesnt. Please let me know how to tackle / achieve it.

The script used for toggling the div is as follows :

```
   $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Also if you have any fixed sidebar demo in bootstrap, please share.

Comment: provide your html too

Comment: You actually need to show what you've tried, pin-point a specific problem that you have. That's how SO works. It's not about sharing code, but fixing existing ones.

Comment: you might want to take a look at the [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) event in jquery

Comment: @ALL, I am still on basic stage, just same html / css / script as in the link shared : http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});

$("#page-content-wrapper").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if $("#wrapper").hasClass("active"){
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    }
});
```

This will allow you to listen for the click on the menu-toggle button when the sidebar is hidden and listen for the click on the rest of the content when the sidebar is visible.

Comment: PERFECT answer.this does the trick mate.However, I havent asked it either, but when the sidebar is toggled ( visible) and I slide left , I need the sidebar to be toggled again. ( Gesture type).Can I achieve it using basic jquery ?

Comment: @CyberWizard If you're talking about swipe gestures, you won't be able to achieve this with JQuery. You can take a look at https://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to create an absolutely positioned div covering the content area you want to click to hide the sidebar you'll have to specify its width and height via CSS.  It will also need its own click event.  Think of it as kind of a huge button that covers the content that is on the left side.  This example does not cover the case of hiding the div if you navigate to a different section.

```
$('#menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
 $('.covers-content').show();
});

$('.covers-content').onClick(function(e) {
 $('#wrapper').toggleClass("active");
 $('.covers-content').hide();
});

<div class="covers-content" style="display:none"></div>
```